# How can i put the next array value into the current key array

Tags: php, arrays

what is the best way to create an array (with unordered indexes) using next index value into the current index. i tried to use next() but didn't help. what i mean is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [8] => b
    [2] => c
    [7] => d
    [9] => e
    [11] => f
)
```

so, i want this data as an array like bellow

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [current] => a
        [next] => b
    )
    [8] => Array
    (
        [current] => b
        [next] => c
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [current] => c
        [next] => d
    )
    [7] => Array
    (
        [current] => d
        [next] => e
    )
    [9] => Array
    (
        [current] => e
        [next] => f
    )
    [11] => Array
    (
        [current] => f
        [next] => 
    )
)
```

what could be the fastest way to do that.

Comment: `foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        $arr[$k] = ["current" => $v, "next" => (isset($arr[$k+1]) ? $arr[$k+1]: "")];` You could also do this by reference, so they would automatically update.

Comment: @Rizier123 why don't you put the comment as answer ? It's the good answer... :D

Comment: Reference example: https://3v4l.org/oba8T

Comment: If you need an array populated with next pointers, why not use an SPLDoublyLinkedList instead

Comment: @Rizier123 Post as an answer m8, I feel your comment is the best answer around..

Comment: @Naruto I didn't understand. @Rizier123 answer alters the array keys in an order different from OP's question, `$k+1` when `$k == 0` will give you `1` instead of `8` (which is actually the next one)

Comment: I'll give it a shot, see if helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For in unordered array

```
$newarray = array();
$length = count($oldarray);
for($i = 0; $i < $length ; ++$i)
{
   $newarray[] = array('current'=>current($oldarray),'next'=>next($oldarray));
}
```

Comment: What if $key+1 does not exist?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the indexes are not ordered indexes. they are unordered.

Comment: @Naruto its return null , exactly like the question

Comment: @Naruto i add @ before that.

Comment: An `@` in code only shows the inabilities of the coder

Comment: @RiggsFolly its not true, its a ability and I can use it.

Comment: Yes but only to hide errors that should not be hidden in code that should not have been written

Comment: @CooPer You can use it to show you can't deal with problems on your code and need to sweep'em under the carpet.

Comment: You obviously dont test any of your code. I just did and its all a mess. First soln messes up the array, second soln does not even compile. _cannot hide that one with an `@` sign_

Comment: I user `@` because I want increase perfomance, I can do it with `isset` but i dont want add another `if`

Comment: Keep trying, there is no justification for the general use of `@` and speed over accuracy is **definitely** not one of them.

Comment: Still does not compile!

Comment: Its a syntax error, why downvote ?  because a `{` ?? I fix this.

Comment: Now it compiles, **but produces the wrong result**. Be a good boy and remove the **spiteful** downvote on @AlanMachado answer. **Why I hear you ask** Because his compiles and produces the required result.

Comment: @RiggsFolly My answer is correct as you see, you can be a good boy. I test it and its get currect result

Comment: Finally, took some effort but you got there in the end

Comment: @RiggsFolly I cant answer to you because im not good in english. You are very pro in php. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

***Note:*** this solution actually **works**, as proven. It was downvoted for some obscure reason.

The simplest solution I can think is the one you've suggested on your own question, with a slight improvement (**[Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/UNYK5)**)

```
<?php
// simulate the array
$arr = [0=>'a',8=>'b',2=>'c',7=>'d',9=>'e',11=>'f'];

// iterate it without messing with its internal pointer
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    $arr[key($arr)] = ["current" => current($arr), "next" => next($arr)];

// test it
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [current] => a
            [next] => b
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [current] => b
            [next] => c
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [current] => c
            [next] => d
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [current] => d
            [next] => e
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [current] => e
            [next] => f
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [current] => f
            [next] => 
        )

)
```

Your goal with this question is the exact purpose of `current()`, `next()` and `key()` functions, so you just have to use them.

Comment: I write same answer ! you just copy that !!

Comment: @CooPer I just reviewed both and mine works, [yours don't](https://3v4l.org/Es4RQ).

Comment: @CooPer This cannot be a copy of your answer. **This one works** Plus it does not use a New Array to hold the results